# Using data from an array retrieved from MongoDB. Using the data to create pushpins on a map

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, mongodb, bing-maps

I'm trying to create an application in c#, WPF which will get data from a MongoDB. The basic quering against the MongoDB I get and I also get data out from the DB, but the geodata I'm trying to use is stored like this: "geo" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  59.28973919,  11.1446193 ] }

So I retrieve the data like this:

```
public static MongoDatabase GetDatabase(string searchText)
{
     MongoServerSettings settings = new MongoServerSettings();
     settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("database.example.com", 27017);
     MongoServer server = new MongoServer(settings);
     MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("tweet_database");
     var collection = database.GetCollection<Tweets>("docs");
     System.Console.WriteLine("5");
     var query = Query.And(Query.Matches("text", searchText),
     Query.NE("geo_enabled", false));

     System.Console.WriteLine("6");
            
     var cursor = collection.Find(query);
     cursor.SetLimit(20);
     System.Console.WriteLine("7");

     //Puts the result from the last query into a list.
     var resultList = cursor.ToList();

     //Iterates over the previous mentioned list and inserts the content into the ObservableCollcetion created earlier.
     foreach (var item in resultList)
     TweetOC.Add(item);
     System.Console.WriteLine(TweetOC.Count);

     return database;
}
```

The data retrieved is stored in:

```
class Docs 
{
    //Create a new Observable collection.
        
    private static ObservableCollection<Tweets> _TweetOC = new ObservableCollection<Tweets>();
    
    public static ObservableCollection<Tweets> TweetOC 
    {
        get { return _TweetOC; }

        set
        {
            _TweetOC = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the "datamodel" is is this

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Tweets 
{

    // The fields here are the ones which are written out ot the datagrid in Mainwindow.xaml.      


    public string text { get; set; }
    public geo geo { get; set; }
```

}

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class geo 
{

    public double[] coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

The XAML is like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
   

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Maptemplate">
        <m:Pushpin m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding geo}" 
           Tag="{Binding}"  
                   
           Content="{Binding text}">
            
            <m:Pushpin.DataContext>
                <local:Tweets/>
            </m:Pushpin.DataContext>

        </m:Pushpin>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<m:Map x:Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="API-Key" Mode="Road"  Margin="1,0,0,0"
           Center="58.1453,7.9571,0.0000" ZoomLevel="9.000" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >            
            <m:Map.Children>
            <m:MapItemsControl
               ItemsSource="{Binding TweetOC}"  
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Maptemplate}" >
                    <m:MapItemsControl.DataContext>
                        <local:Docs/>
                    </m:MapItemsControl.DataContext>
                </m:MapItemsControl>
                <m:MapLayer x:Name="ContentPopupLayer">
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentPopup"
                          Visibility="Collapsed"
                          Background="White"
                          Opacity="0.85">
                            <StackPanel Margin="15">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPopupText"
                                     FontSize="12"
                                     FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPopupDescription"
                                         FontSize="12"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </m:MapLayer>           
        </m:Map.Children>
    </m:Map>
```

A few things are obviously excluded because I didn't think they were relevant.

My question is: How can I use the geodata or the array that the geodata is stored in to autogenerate pushpins on the map? Right now I think the problem is the conversion between the array in the geo-class and the location type used by Bing maps. Based on this errormessage when I retrieve data: System.Windows.Data Error: 1 :

Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'WpfApplication1.geo' and 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=geo; DataItem='Tweets' (HashCode=7643053); target element is 'Pushpin' (Name=''); target property is 'Position' (type 'Location')

Either that or my solution is completely wrong. So can someone please point me in the right direction?

And I know a lot of the coding and structure is bad, but so far in the project, functionality > structure and best practice.

Thanks in advance.

## Update

The custom converter i tried writing and using, note that the convert back is never going to be used so I just typed something in there to make it compile:

```
public class GeoConverter : IValueConverter
{
   
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object geo = value;

        double asDouble = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        return asDouble;
    }
    
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        object geo = value;

        double asDouble = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        return asDouble;
    }
}
```

When I try to use use this I get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'WpfApplication1.geo' to type 'System.IConvertible.

Comment: The error is very clear. Where is your converter class to handle the data conversion required? Look for `IValueConverter` for examples.

Comment: I tried writing a custom converter, (will update the question with it) but it didn't work, mostly because I'm a little uncertain what I should actually convert to and how since the data is stored in arrays.